# Excel Macro Autofilter and Delete Rows

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, autofilter

I am trying to get the coding below working but getting errors.

Coding selects another worksheet, then autofilter a column and delete row.

Line having trouble is .AutoFilter 1, "*NoNo*"

Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range clas failed.

Can I please get some assistance.

```
Private Sub Project()
Worksheets("YesYes").Select
With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
 With Range("y1", Range("y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, "*NoNo*"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete any row that contains "NoNo" in column y?

Comment: Works for me... are you sure there is data in column y?

Comment: Yes, trying to delete rows with "NoNo" in column y. The macro above works if the button is in the same sheet as the table, but I have the button in another sheet and this is causing an error. Unfortunately I need the button in the different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting does not necessarily "Activate" the worksheet.  Instead of:

```
Worksheets("YesYes").Select
With ActiveSheet
```

Do this:

```
Worksheets("YesYes").Activate
With ActiveSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

99% of the times using `Select` or `Activate` is not necessary.

Instead use fully qualified objects, in your case use:

```
With Worksheets("YesYes")
```

And nested below use:

```
With .Range("y1", .Range("y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

And then add the rest of your code.